# Webcam not working on Asus eee PC

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, drivers, webcam, eee-pc

I recently bought an Asus eee PC 901 and the webcam doesn't work with the pre-installed Windows XP Home edition or Ubuntu Netbook Remix. When I disable the camera from the system tray and enable it again, the system detects an unknown USB 2.0 device which I assume is the camera. Any idea how to get it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EasyPeasy wiki has [this](http://wiki.geteasypeasy.com/EeePC_901#Webcam_.26_Bluetooth) article, though it seems you may have already tried that.

You mention you bought it recently. In that case, the best way to fix this problem is to call Asus and chime in on the warranty to get a replacement netbook. Just don't forget to be pushy, but not scary-pushy.

Comment: Looked everywhere on this one. I finally wound up sending it to an Asus service center in Newark, California. It took some convincing on the phone but in the end they saw it my way. I guess you get what you pay for when you spend $170.